# Screen goes black when trying to switch users on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, dell, crash, switch-user

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Dell XPS L502X laptop last night. I set it up as a dual boot with Windows 8.1. I was testing the GUI to make sure all features work.

Examples: Software Updater for the latest updates, tweaking the System settings to my personal taste, setting up wireless network, etc.

The only things I tweaked were uninstalling Thunderbird and removing the mail icon on the system bar, and changed the wireless icon on my laptop from blinking light -> solid light.

I click on the power icon in the upper right corner of the system bar. I scroll down to Guest session to switch user. When I click switch user, my monitor goes black. Nothing happens. Pressing "enter" or any keys on the keyboard does not change or manipulate the screen. The only thing I can do is use the command:

> Alt+PrntScr REISUB

It reboots the laptop

Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: its a known issue of 13.10..

Comment: Make sure that you have the necessary graphics drivers installed.

Comment: @Sushantp606 Do you have a link to the bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (dell M3800 with optimus graphics) on a clean install of 13.10, but the updates I installed this morning seem to have fixed it.  I can now switch users fine either from the "cog" menu or from the lock screen